# Does J1 visa need to be valid to apply for J2 visa?

Tags: j-visa

I am a J1 visa holder; this expires by the end of November, 2018. I have the new DS2019 extended for more one year (i.e. up to 30 Nov, 2019).
Since I am planning to go to India in January 2019, I was applying for a visa again, but recently got to know that I am eligible for a visa interview waiver.
 Now the problem is that I and my wife (new J2 dependent visa applicant) were going to take the appointment together.

My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible for me not to opt of the Dropbox facility option (visa interview waiver) and instead attend the interview with her?
2. If I use the Dropbox facility, I know that it will take some time to get the new visa stamp. In the meantime, can my wife go for the interview? Because at that time I will not have a valid visa either and I will be outside of the USA.